# Why we shouldn't keep our code in our web server's root folder?

Tags: python, django

I started learning Django, in [official website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/)(as you can see from the image below) it says we shouldn't keep our code in server's root folder but we need to keep it somewhere outside the root folder.

I didn't understand two things

1) How we will be able to run our project without keeping the code in root folder?

2) How is it safe to keep the code in /home/mycode folder than keeping it in /var/www ?

[image: As you can see below]

Comment: Quoting the page: "It’s not a good idea to put any of this Python code within your Web server’s document root, **because it risks the possibility that people may be able to view your code over the Web**."

Comment: How it is not a risk to keep it in another folder? people will still be able to see other folders right?

Comment: I sure hope not @sudheersuri. If people can see arbitrary folders on your server, you have bigger problems.

Comment: if people can see /var/www , what will stop them to see /home/mycode folder?

Comment: Did you know the answer now my friend?